# How to make a conditional on an annotation I created?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my project I created the following class annotation:

```
@CustomController //created by me, it is an alias for spring's @Controller
public class AController{

}
```

The custom controller being defined like this:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
@Controller
public @interface CustomController{

@AliasFor(annotation = Controller.class)
String value() default "";
```

Now, I'd like to instantiate a bean **if at least one @CustomController** has been defined.

I couldn't find any @ConditionalOn* annotation that could apply to this specific case, should I create a custom Condition? How to do that?

Comment: Is `@ConditionalOnBean(annotation = @CustomController)` the one you are looking for? If so, please note that Javadoc saying "The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context _so far_"

Comment: Sweet! Didn't know it could be used this way as well! If you answer me I'll mark it as the correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot provides the annotation `@ConditionalOnBean` that matches if a bean in the application context matches the given requirements.

One of those requirements could be that a bean is annotated with a given annotation:

```java
@ConditionalOnBean(annotation = @CustomController)
```

Please be careful that this condition may not always work as expected if used on regular beans or configuration classes:

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context ***so far*** and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only. If a candidate bean may be created by another auto-configuration, make sure that the one using this condition runs after.

See also the [Javadoc of @ConditionalOnBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnBean.html) and [Creating Your Own Auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration).